# create a certificate chain (Self Signed) for Azure Web App

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

How can I create a certificate chain (Self Signed) for Azure Web App? I turned on the settings in the code and Incoming client certificates.

But in the logs I see an error:

> OfflineRevocation The revocation function was unable to check revocation because the revocation server was offline
>
> Certificate was not authenticated. Failure message: Client certificate failed validation.

Comment: Did you fnd a way to solve your issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the [New-SelfSignedCertificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/pkiclient/new-selfsignedcertificate?view=win10-ps) command from Powershell to create a new self-signed certificate for testing purposes. For example:

```
PS C:\> New-SelfSignedCertificate -DnsName "www.fabrikam.com", "www.contoso.com" -CertStoreLocation "cert:\LocalMachine\My"
```

This creates a self-signed SSL server certificate in the computer MY store with the subject alternative name set to www.fabrikam.com, www.contoso.com and Subject and Issuer name set to www.fabrikam.com.

Once you have the cert, you may [upload it to your App service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate#upload-certificate-to-app-service). Check [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/fee5d70f-b701-420b-85f5-be67eda904a5/add-ssl-binding-with-self-certificate-is-not-working?forum=windowsazurewebsitespreview) post on MSDN for more details on the working solution. However, do note that you might still see some certificate validation errors if the cert is self-signed. Consider using a free App Service Managed Certificate or the App Service certificate as they already satisfy the prerequisites of App Service.

Hope this helps.

References:

- [Add an SSL certificate in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate)
- [Secure a custom domain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-bindings#secure-a-custom-domain)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I was mistaken in the wording of my question. I am using a certificate chain from my local certificate authority. For use an SSL certificate in my code in Azure App Service. It looks like in this article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate-in-code. But I have the error Certificate was not authenticated. Failure message: Client certificate failed validation.